# Scrape text from tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working for a project and I would like to scrape some information to make a database from many websites.
I learned a little Python and how to use BeautifulSoup library and tried the below.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://paris.quel-institut-beaute.com/').read()

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

soup = soup.find_all("div", class_="ic")
print (soup)
```

When I try to take only text using an attribute, it says to me it is not possible. Any help ?

Comment: First of all you are overwritting soup.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code a bit by utilizing the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), it's more high level than `urllib`. You can also use CSS selectors for extracting tags from the page source, they're a bit cleaner and generally more robust to use. [BeautifulSoup docs contain plenty of useful into on them.](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://paris.quel-institut-beaute.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

# soup.select() will return a list of all tags with class 'ic'
stores = soup.select('.ic')
```

If you're trying to call `get_text()` or `text` on the list, it won't work. Instead, you need to iterate over the elements in the list to get text from them.

```
for tag in stores:
    print(tag.get_text(strip=True))
```

If you are going to make multiple requests from the same script, [use a Session object from the Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). It will use the same TCP connection, improving the performance.

This goes beyond the scope of the question, but if you want to serialize the store information, you can do it like this:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://paris.quel-institut-beaute.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
stores = soup.select('.ic')

store_details = OrderedDict()
for store in stores:
    store_name = store.select_one('h3').get_text()
    store_address = store.select_one('.street-address').get_text()
    postal_code = store.select_one('.postal-code').get_text()
    locality = store.select_one('.locality').get_text()

    store_details[store_name] = {
        'store_address': store_address,
        'postal_code': postal_code,
        'locality': locality
    }

shop_details_json = json.dumps(store_details, indent=4, separators=(',', ':'))
```

You can print `shop_details_json` to see the information stored in the form of a series of dictionaries, using store name as key and address as the value.

Comment: Good and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an iterator back, so you need to display each one in a for loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('http://paris.quel-institut-beaute.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all("div", class_="ic"):
    print(div.get_text(strip=True))
```

Giving you:

```
En savoir plusDelicates Attentions425 avis8 Passage Du Guesclin75015Paris
En savoir plusInstitut Du Regard53 avis30 Rue de Lagny75020Paris
En savoir plusEtoile Nails420 avis27 Av. Ledru Rollin75012Paris
En savoir plusInstitut Marie Pauline485 avis9 Boulevard Arago75013Paris
En savoir plusInstitut Pyrene524 avis2 Rue Greffulhe75008Paris
En savoir plusNymphee12 avis28 Rue Glaciere75013Paris
En savoir plusGrain De Beaute430 avis1 Rue Petion75011Paris
En savoir plusOumy Esthetique23 avis1 Rue Tanneries75013Paris
En savoir plusEric Nicolas Louis11 avis50 Boulevard Arago75013Paris
En savoir plusBiozen519 avis26 Boulevard de Magenta75010Paris
En savoir plusBulle De Soins411 avis149 Rue Raymond Losserand75014Paris
En savoir plusCryominceur0aucun avis19 Rue Nicolo75116Paris
En savoir plusAU TEMPS D'UN SOIN57 avis55 rue de Turbigo75003Paris
En savoir plusLe Boudoir Parisien41 avis251, avenue Daumesnil75012Paris
En savoir plusAlex'sthetik0aucun avis49, rue St Placide75006Paris
```